# Uniform convergence on $[-K,K]$ implies uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

If $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $[-K,K]$ for every $K \in \mathbb R$ does it follow that $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: No. Consider the Taylor series for the exponential, for example: the convergence of the Taylor polynomials is uniform on all compact sets, but not uniform on the whole line.

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{n})x$ converges to $x$ uniformly on any compact set.

Comment: You could also take $g_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}$The comments adequately answer the original question. Here's a conceptual reason one can't expect an affirmative answer:

To say $(g_{n}) \to g$ uniformly on $[-K, K]$ means that for every $\eps > 0$, there exists an $N = N(\eps, K)$ (i.e., depending on both $\eps$ and $K$) such that
$$
\tag{1}
|g_{n}(x) - g(x)| < \eps
  \quad\text{for $n \geq N$ and all $x$ with $|x| \leq K$.}
$$

To say $(g_{n}) \to g$ uniformly on $\R$ means that for every $\eps > 0$, there exists an $N = N(\eps)$ such that
$$
\tag{2}
|g_{n}(x) - g(x)| < \eps
  \quad\text{for $n \geq N$ and all real $x$.}
$$

Suppose $(g_{n}) \to g$ uniformly on $[-K, K]$ for every $K > 0$. If $\eps > 0$ is fixed, there exists a *function* $K \mapsto N(\eps, K)$ satisfying (1). However, there is no guarantee that this function is *bounded* for each $\eps$, i.e., no guarantee that there is a *single* $N = N(\eps)$ satisfying (2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if $g_n \to g$ not uniformly on $\mathbb R$ could one prove the weaker result that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ (given that $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $[-K,K]$ and $g_n$ continuous)?

Comment: That is, if $g$ is continuous on $[-K,K]$ for every $K$, is $g$ continuous on all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @newb: Yes; continuity is determined locally. :)